# Environment variables are not passed to sub scripts while running on crontab

Tags: shell-script, cron, environment-variables

I was trying to run one of the scripts (for example, `wrapper.sh`) which internally executes other scripts using crontab. It works fine without any issues.

When I have created a environment file (which stores the passwords-DB and paths) and trying to execute the main script (`wrapper.sh`) the cron entry doesn't work on those scripts which are called internally in the wrapper.

NOTE:
I tried changing PATH, added env file location before the script in cron but it still didn't work:

```
9 9 * * * . /$SOMEPATH/some.env; /$SOMEPATH/wrapper.sh
```

The environment script and `wrapper.sh` are in same path. when the cron runs it passes the env variables to wrapper but not to the scripts which are called internally in wrapper. Also a mail is received on `/var/mail/$user` saying the env file as "No such file or Directory". I've gone through many posts but couldn't figure out the resolution.

Answer (score 3):

`$SOMEPATH` isn't defined within `cron`, so your `crontab` line that tries to source `/$SOMEPATH/some.env` will fail. (Unless `//some.env` exists, that is.)

For debugging `cron` related issues, be aware that it writes *stderr* messages - including its own - to the local user's mailbox. If you don't have a mail client installed (`mail` or `mailx`) you could use something like this to read these messages:

```
less /var/mail/$USER
```

Or if you want to be really generic

```
"${PAGER:-less}" "${MAIL:-/var/mail/${USER:-${LOGIN:-$(whoami)}}}"
```